# Create a Navigation Drawer layout for homepage

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have customized the default `Android Studio` `ActionBar Tab + Swipe Views` and now I would like to have a homepage where I have a `Navigation Drawer`  layout that when I swipe It to left I enter in tabs layout. Could You help me please?  I don't know where to start.

**EDIT**
This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String welcomeScreenShownPref = "welcomeScreenShown";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Boolean welcomeScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);

    if (!welcomeScreenShown) {


        String whatsNewText = getResources().getString(R.string.Text);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT).setMessage(whatsNewText).setPositiveButton(
                android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
    }

    mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_color)));
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

    });
    for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));

    }

}

public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    //final int NUM_ITEMS = 11; // number of tabs

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Tab1Activity();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2Activity();
            case 2:
                return new Tab3Activity();
            case 3:
                return new Tab4Activity();
            case 4:
                return new Tab5Activity();
            case 5:
                return new Tab6Activity();
            case 6:
                return new Tab7Activity();
            case 7:
                return new Tab8Activity();
            case 8:
                return new Tab9Activity();
            case 9:
                return new Tab10Activity();
            case 10:
                return new Tab11Activity();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 11;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.label1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.label2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.label3);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.label4);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.label5);
            case 5:
                return getString(R.string.label6);
            case 6:
                return getString(R.string.label7);
            case 7:
                return getString(R.string.label8);
            case 8:
                return getString(R.string.label9);
            case 9:
                return getString(R.string.label10);
            case 10:
                return getString(R.string.label11);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if (i == R.id.actiorn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here I have 11 tabs so 11 layouts but there's no actionbar.
I just want the `Navigation Drawer` for homepage with trasparent actionbar (I made a schematic drawing for you to understand better). 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on how to create Navigation Drawer in Android.

Or you have some problems implementing it? If so, provide details.

Comment: I edited the question, I know how to have the `Navigation Drawer` following the guide but I don't know how to adapt the code for what I want with what I have now.

Comment: First, you should change your layout according to documentation (Create a Drawer Layout section), but instead of FrameLayout you should insert your current view hierarchy (the one you have in your layout file now).
Second, you should populate the ListView of Drawer with some items (Initialize the Drawer List section).
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the activity_main:
_<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />_
Should I insert this instead of FrameLayout?

Comment: Yes, but without xmlns:android attribute, like this: _<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/pager" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />_

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear about that, in the homepage I want the Navigation Drawer but when I swipe the layout to left I have what I have now, that is ActionBar tabs + Swipe Views. What you're saying is only Navigation Drawer

Comment: Can you please attach activity_main layout file?

Comment: My activity_main is in the comment above

Comment: Then you'll have Navigation Drawer and your content both. In the new layout you have two main views inside DrawerLayout: your content (ViewPager) and ListView which is used for Navigation Drawer. Application will display your ViewPager after start, but if you swipe from left to right Navigation Drawer will appear (it can be closed by right to left swipe).

Comment: So the last question: if I have both layout in one then in the MainActivity that I have now where there is _setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)_ what should I have in Navigation Drawer java class?

Comment: You don't need Navigation Drawer class. Just change your layout and you'll get empty Navigation Drawer. To initialize it with some data, please, refer "Initialize the Drawer List" section in documentation.

Comment: No I tried but you still don't understand what I want. I open the app and I have a HOMEPAGE that is a Navigation Drawer layout where there is the panel from the right side connected to the 11 tabs I already have. Now to start reading what's in the tabs layout you have to slide your finger to left to close the ND layout and there there is the swipe views between tabs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61226/discussion-between-ayzen-and-riccardo-fabozzi).